# How can I add a fixed sidebar to a web page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have created a [simple web site](http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/) with ASP.NET using Visual Studio and Web Matrix. It's pretty basic, and is a "one-trick pony" you might say - it allows you to read various works by Mark Twain where the text is colorized based on who is "talking."

Since in some cases there may be dozens of "voices" and thus that many colors used, this can be a challenge for the reader to remember which color goes with which character (although there is a popup/hover hint that tells you). I have a "Dialog Colorization Table" near the beginning of each work (Huck Finn, Tom Sawyer, Roughing It, and Innocents Abroad are the works currently finished).

However, if a person forgets/doesn't know about the hover hints telling them who the speaker is, they may feel compelled to scroll all the way back to the top to remind themselves of who is "sky blue" etc. Obviously an irritating endeavor.

A friend (actually, an author of several books about Twain with whom I've been corresponding) recommended affixing the "voice table" to the side of the page, like so:

[image]

I think this is a great idea, but don't know how difficult this will be to put into practice. Currently, the "free area" on the margins are simply that - wide margins. I don't know enough about HTML and CSS (and jQuery?) to know how involved converting this "blank space" to a fixed area for the "Dialog Colorization Table".

Is it possible to make this change/addition without too much trouble? If so, how?

### UPDATE

Of course, this would mean having to swap out the particular "fixed table" each time the user changed documents (the list for Huck Finn is not the same as the list for Tom Sawyer, etc.)

Perhaps the thing to do is to pop up the entire "voice table" in the "OnHover" event, somehow highlighting the current one. e.g., if Tom was speaking, make the "This is Tom Sawyer speaking" row in the table bold, or some such)

Comment: `CSS`'s property [`position: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)?

Comment: I think there's a lot more to it than that; there's got to be some "tricky" HTML involved to make my simple "one column" page into two (three, with the left column still being "blank"?) or some such. Once that is done, though (and "if"), perhaps that property would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before changing anything, please make sure you've got a backup.**

Simple result made in Fiddle (demonstration only): http://jsfiddle.net/marc_g/6y10v1fj/

Currently your website has a content width of 960px. The stylesheet which you are using, contains the following code:

```
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

If you would like to add a sidebar, you've first got to extend the width of the content-wrapper class. Replace the lines mentioned above, in your stylesheet, with the following:

```
.content-wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 1180px;
}
```

You've now got 220 extra pixels available for your sidebar.

Then you've got to create a extra stylesheet-division for your sidebar. You can do this by adding the following code to your stylesheet:

```
#sidebar_right {
   background: #000;
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
   top: 20%;
   position: fixed;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Also add the 'tabs' stylesheet-division to the stylesheet, since I've noticed this div isn't declared yet. We have to float the content to the left side. You can do this by adding the following code to your stylesheet:

```
#tabs{
   width: 960px;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
}
```

Then you've got to add the sidebar div class to your .html page. Use the following code after you've closed the div **'tabs'**, probably on line 113 in your HTML file:

```
<div id="sidebar_right">&nbsp;</div>
```

After that, replace the nbsp with the ul element and it's li elements like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="joanna.html" title="Description">Joanna</a></li>
    <li><a href="joanna2.html" title="Description">Joanna2</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you would like to style this, you can do this by adding the following code to the stylesheet:

```
#sidebar_right ul{
   padding:20px;
   float: left;
}

#sidebar_right ul li{
   list-style: none;
}

#sidebar_right ul li a{
   height: 25px;
   width: 160px;
   color: #FFF;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp for extra information about the ul and li elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
.mydiv {
position:fixed;
top: 50px;
right: 50px;
}
```

Change top and right as needed. Or if you prefer bottom and left.